# Why is UITextField animating on resignFirstResponder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

Since iOS 8, UITextFields in a form behave very strangely. If I click an another text field or press Tab on the keyboard, the entered text animates upwards then reappears quickly. It happens every time after the view did loaded, and every now and then afterwards.

It looks like this:

[image: Animation]

My code looks like this:

```
#pragma mark - <UITextFieldDelegate>

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        [self loginButtonClicked:nil];
    } else if (textField == self.emailTextField) {
        [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

EDIT:

It looks like this issue is caused by my keyboard listeners:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    self.loginBoxBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = 0;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    CGRect frame = [sender.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect newFrame = [self.view convertRect:frame fromView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window];
    self.loginBoxBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(newFrame);

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Its works fine for me. Are you using some third party sub class of UITextField ?

Comment: No, I don't. It's a plain `UITextField`, and I use no 3rd party library or whatever.

Comment: Are you checking on Simulator? If yes are you using external keyboard ?

Comment: It's the same in the Simulator and on real device, with or without keyboard attached.

Comment: Can you create a sample project with textfield as its really difficult to understand what might be the reason.

Comment: I have created an empty demo project, and I am now sure the animation is a side effect of my keyboard listeners. I edited my initial question to include the code for that.

Comment: please let me know what is 'loginBoxBottomLayoutConstraint' and 'noticeView' so that i can replicate it at my end

Comment: There is a `UIView` (`loginBox`) containing the two `UITextField`s. The login box is tied to the bottom of it's superview with `loginBoxBottomLayoutConstraint`. Sorry about `noticeView`, I left it in the code non intentionally, it is not relevant.

Comment: I have prepared a test repo for you: https://github.com/gklka/TextFieldAnimationPoC

Comment: Is this a sailing app @gklka

Comment: @Charlie yes, it is.

Comment: Nice! Do you race too? @gklka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are executing the piece of code in

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)sender
```

even if the keyboard is already active, which leads to some distortion.

A small work around would be to check if the keyboard is already active before adjusting the frames, as below

```
bool isKeyboardActive = false;

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)sender

{

    self.boxBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    isKeyboardActive = false;
}


-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)sender

{

    if (!isKeyboardActive) {
        CGRect frame = [sender.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        CGRect newFrame = [self.view convertRect:frame fromView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window];
        self.boxBottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(newFrame);
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        isKeyboardActive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    [textField layoutIfNeeded]; 
 }
```

Which I guess should resolve your issue. Got some similar post at [UITextField: When beginning input, textfield bounces up, and then bounces down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264093/uitextfield-when-beginning-input-textfield-bounces-up-and-then-bounces-down)

[IOS8 Text in TextField Bounces on Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774212/ios8-text-in-textfield-bounces-on-focus)

Let me know if still we have issue

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in this

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
// Changes we don't want animated here
}];
```

Comment: Like what? I don't understand what should I put into the non animated block.

Comment: I would assume `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];`